# Python GUI entry point not working on Bash for Windows

Tags: python, windows, git-bash, setuptools, pyside2

I have a Python GUI app (using either PyQt5 or PySide2) which I would like to start with the command `mypackage`. Therefore, I added the following section to `setup.cfg`:

```
[options.entry_points]
gui_scripts =
    mypackage = mypackage:main
```

On Linux and macOS, installing the package with `pip` successfully creates a `mypackage` command which starts the app. However, on Windows I get an error message after typing `mypackage` in a Git Bash terminal: a dialog pops up titled "Fatal Error in Launcher" saying "stderr duplication failed". Note that everything works fine when I use Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) or Power Shell (`powershell.exe`).

Relevant package structure:

```
mypackage/
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
    pyproject.toml
    setup.cfg
```

`__init__.py`:

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

                                           
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    label = QLabel("Hello World", alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    label.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`__main__.py`:

```py
from . import main


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

`setup.cfg`:

```
[metadata]
name = mypackage
version = 0.0.1

[options]
packages = mypackage

[options.entry_points]
gui_scripts =
    mypackage = mypackage:main
```

Steps to reproduce:

0. Install Python (3.9.8 from https://www.python.org/) and then `pip install PySide2`
1. Open a Git Bash on Windows and change into the root project folder `mypackage`
2. `pip install .`
3. Type `mypackage` – a dialog with the error pops up

Again, if I use Command Prompt or Power Shell in step 3, everything works!

All files are available in this repo: https://github.com/cbrnr/stderr-duplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a bug which has been fixed in https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10875. Using pip ≥ 22.3 should now work.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced the same problem and realized that it was because I had not defined `main()` in my PyQt application. From pouring over SO posts and PyQt tutorials, it doesn't appear that defining `main()` is a convention (I would be interested to know why this is). To fix this this I did some simple restructuring:

**Old**

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**Restructured**

```py
def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This allowed my to use the entry point in `setup.py`

```py
entry_points={
        'console_scripts':[
            'my_gui=my_gui:main',
            ]}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I don't think this is the problem. I already have a [`main()` function](https://github.com/cbrnr/mnelab/blob/main/mnelab/__main__.py#L73), and the value `'mnelab=mnelab.__main__:main'` means exactly that: the `main()` function in the `mnelab.__main__` module.

Comment: No problem, sorry it wasn't of more use. I understand that those calls should refer to the same value, but I couldn't get my entry point working with `__main__` for whatever reason. I don't know if that was syntactical (other characters like `-` can be tricky too), or something specific to my code.

Comment: I think you need to provide *any* function name and it will work.

Comment: I moved the `main()` function out of `__main__.py` into `__init__.py`, and now the `gui_scripts` entry point works even on Windows (for details see my changes in https://github.com/cbrnr/mnelab/pull/224). Not sure why this is the case though, but apparently `mnelab:main` works and `mnelab.__main__.main` didn't.

Comment: Actually, never mind my previous comment, the `gui_scripts` entry point still doesn't work on Windows. I still get the "stderr duplication failed" error message.

Comment: This seems to be a problem of which shell I'm using to start the program. Whereas I get the error when using Git Bash, it works perfectly fine when using Command Prompt (aka cmd.exe).

Comment: I have restructured my question and included a new minimal example that is much easier to reproduce.